# How to access slots using add_directive with an updated intent [python]

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

This is my code that should go to another intent handler.

```
return handler_input.response_builder\
  .add_directive(DelegateDirective(updated_intent="Intent2"))\
  .speak(speech_text)\
  .set_should_end_session(False)\
  .response
```

And this is my second intent handler code:

```
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_intent_name("Intent2"))
def intent2_handler(handler_input):
    """Handler for Cancel Home Tour Intent."""
    slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots
    session_attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.session_attributes

    x = slots["my_slot"] <--- causes error
```

I'm getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` . It seems like I can't access my slots. Am I using `add_directive(DelegateDirective(updated_intent="Intent2"))` right?

Comment: If you reach that handler it means that you are in `Intent2`. So the problem could be in the slot; are you sure that the slot is filled? Try logging handler input and see what's in there.

Comment: For delegation you could use this `DelegateDirective(updated_intent=Intent(name='Intent2'))` but shoud be working even with your sintax